# Remapping topics in gazebo, not working?

Tags: gazebo, roslaunch, camera, remapping, remap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to remap a camera stream from /camera to /camera1_ns in gazebo.

```
<launch>
  <!-- set use_sim_time flag -->
  <param name="/use_sim_time" value="true" />

  <!-- start gazebo with an empty plane -->
  <node name="gazebo" pkg="gazebo" type="gazebo" args="$(find gazebo_worlds)/worlds/empty.world" respawn="false" output="screen"/>

<!-- start gui -->
<node name="gazebo_gui" pkg="gazebo" type="gui" respawn="false" output="screen"/>

<!-- spawn model -->
 <node name="spawn_arm" pkg="gazebo" type="spawn_model" args="-file simple_arm.model -gazebo -model     simple_arm" respawn="false" output="screen" >

<!-- remapping topics -->

<remap from="/camera1_ns" to="/camera" />
</node>

</launch>
```

But there is no /camera1_ns listed with rostopic list. Is this approach correct or should it be done otherwise?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/50931/remapping-topics-in-gazebo,-not-working?/) by [davinci](https://answers.ros.org/users/3014/davinci/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2573 on 2012-12-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Does it help to delete the leading '/' in the remapped names?

```
<remap from="camera" to="camera1_ns" />
```

EDIT: Maybe I got the names backwards from what you intended?

EDIT2: Move the remap from the arm_spawn node to the gazebo node.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-12-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [davinci](https://answers.ros.org/users/3014/davinci/) on 2012-12-24**:
Thanks for your response. But it does not work. I should be able to see a camera1_ns using rostopic list?

**Comment by [davinci](https://answers.ros.org/users/3014/davinci/) on 2012-12-29**:
I am indeed remapping camera to camera1_ns But still not getting it to work...no camera1_ns is appearing in rostopic list. Tried it in several ways. Is the position of the remap argument okay?

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-12-29**:
It is inside the spawn_arm node. Maybe you should move it to the gazebo node?

**Comment by [davinci](https://answers.ros.org/users/3014/davinci/) on 2012-12-30**:
Yes, that works! Thanks! Seemed illogical as the simulation doesn't know anything yet about camera's at that point, but it seems to be the correct way.